# PowerShell execution policy set but not recognized when invoked from .Net program

Tags: powershell

I have created a small program in Visual Studio - a form with a button to execute the program when clicked - and built the .exe.

This program is supposed to open PowerShell and run a ps1 file.

When I run it from within VS in debug mode, it works as expected running the ps1 script without error.
When I build the project and run the exe as an administrator, it briefly opens PowerShell but closes immediately.

The output file states that the execution of scripts is disabled on this system, although this is incorrect as I can run any number of PowerShell scripts manually by right clicking them and running them with PowerShell.

I have tried changing the execution policy from Signed, to AllSigned, as well as Unrestricted, but it did not help.

Here is my code:

```
    if (File.Exists("LiveSiteTests.ps1"))
        {
            File.GetAttributes("LiveSiteTests.ps1");
            string strCmdText =       Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "LiveSiteTests.ps1");
            var process = new Process();

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"&'" + strCmdText + "'\"";


            process.Start();
            string s = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            process.WaitForExit();

            using (StreamWriter outfile = new      StreamWriter("StandardOutput.txt", true))
            {
                outfile.Write(s);
            }

        }
```

Comment: As a general practice - you can use the parameters `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "d:\path\scriptfile.ps1" <args>` on the powershell.exe command line to run a script. Run `powershell /?` at a prompt for more information.

Comment: Is this possibly an issue with 32 vs 64 bit? Have you set the execution policy in one environment but not the other, and then your debug vs release executables are also executing in different modes?

Comment: [For reference, here is information about 32 vs 64 bit System paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332305/3905079) (you might think you're always referencing the same executable with your `C:\Windows\System32` path, but the situation is more complicated).

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  32 vs 64 bit did not occur to me so I will check that out.  I will update if that solves the problem.