# How to resolve Class not registered error for PowerShell Script in InstallShield 2015?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, installshield, powershell-4.0, installshield-2015

I have a PowerShell script which works fine if executed manually but when i try to execute it by creating a function in InstallShield 2015, it fails with below error -

> get-webconfiguration : Retrieving COM class factory for component with
>   CLSID 80040154 class not registered 
>   {688EEEE5-6A7E-422F-B2E1-6AF00DC944A6} FAILED DUE TO THE FOLLOWING
>   ERROR : 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0X80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Below is the InstallShield function which is called during installation to update the Physical path of the Virtual application in IIS.

```
function VirtualAppPowershell()

    STRING szMsg, szCmdLine, szAppPath1, szDir;
    NUMBER nResult;
    STRING szFile, svDir;

begin                               

    try
        szAppPath1 = "powershell.exe";
        //szAppPath1 = "powershell_ise.exe";

        szDir = TARGETDIR;

        svDir = TARGETDIR + "Demo\\Script\\";
        szCmdLine = "-File .\\VirtualAppPathChange.ps1 \"" + svDir +"\\\""; 


        StrRemoveLastSlash (svDir);

        ChangeDirectory(svDir);

        szMsg = "Updating PhysicalPath of Virtual application";                                    

        SdShowMsg ( szMsg , TRUE );
        Delay (5);       
        nResult = LaunchAppAndWait (szAppPath1, szCmdLine, WAIT|LAAW_OPTION_MINIMIZED);
        SdShowMsg ( szMsg , FALSE );  

    catch
        WriteLogAsError(FALSE, Err.Number, Err.Description);
        Err.Raise();
    endcatch;

    return nResult;
end;
```

Here is the code of PowerShell Script as well for reference-

```
#Code to get PhysicalPath of Virtual application
$WebClientPath=(get-webapplication DemoApp).PhysicalPath

# Code to get Installation Directory path
$CommonNode=Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Demo\Platform\Common
$InstallationDir=$CommonNode.InstallationDir

#Appended new foldername to $Path1
$Path1= $InstallationDir + "Test\"

#Appended old foldername to $Path2
$Path2= $InstallationDir + "Dem\"


# Code to get Version of application
$PlatformNode=Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Demo\Platform
$Version=$PlatformNode.VERSION

if($Version -ge "7.3.0.0")
{
    Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\DemoApp' -Name physicalPath -Value "$Path1"
}
else
{
    Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\DemoApp' -Name physicalPath -Value "$Path2"
}
```

Note - **My OS is 64 bit.**

Comment: I usually see this error when trying to use COM objects in the wrong bit-ness, i.e., your InstallShield is running as 32-bit and trying to create a 64-bit COM object or vice versa.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1, So is there any other way by which i can update the physical path of existing Virtual application in IIS by InstallShield - InstallScript installer during installation and again set the phyical path back to the old during uninstallation?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same problem. Already tried to execute with powershell 32bits and 64bits with the same error.

Comment: Had the problem with Jenkins executing a powershell maybe is the same problem. Solved by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331924/jenkins-powershell-plugin-is-running-32-bit-powershell-and-i-need-64bit